# Run Octave function with one argument from batch

Tags: function, batch-file, octave, eval

I am trying to run an octave function from a batch file. The function is well written given how it works when launched from within the Octave GUI.
The batch file, other than pointing to the octave function, defines the only argument needed by it.
A while back this was not a function but a simple Octave script and the commands used were ok.
The only issue I am encountering now is being able to pass the variable calculated by the batch file onto the octave function.

I have recently written an octave function to do some file management. It requires only one input from the user:

```
function replace_TMM (file_base)
```

where file_base is a string to specify what directory I am working on. So it has to be something like "Z:" or "I:" or so on.
I am quite sure that the function is well written since I am able to use it from Octave GUI without any issues.
The fact is that I would like to run this function from a batch file. Inside this batch file I wrote:

```
SET a=%cd:~0,2%
```

This command is able to identify the working directory so "a" will be equal to "Z:" or similars.
Now my issue is telling the batch file to evaluate the octave function using "a" as its input argument.
I tried stuff like:

```
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe" -q --eval _03_REPLACE_V04("'%cd:~0,2%'")
```

which does not seem to work. This kind of solution gives a syntax error at batch level, it is not even able to enter the octave file.

If I instead try something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe" -q _03_REPLACE_V04.m Z:
```

It is able to enter the octave file but it does not process the function, just skips over it to get to the end of the script.

Same goes if I try the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe" _03_REPLACE_V04.m -"Z:"
```

In brief I bvelieve that the function itself works, it is only a matter of passing a variable from the batch to the octave.

Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

I have done what was suggested by @Dariush Gavari and used the following syntax:

```
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe" -q --eval "replace_TMM('%a%')"
```

This gets me the following error message:

```
error: 'replace_TMM' undefined near line 1, column 1
```

I believed that it was because it was not ablòe to find the script containing the function. This is saved in a file called _03_REPLACE_V04.m
For this reason I have tried with

```
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe" -q --eval _03_REPLACE_V04.m "replace_TMM('%a%')"
```

Leading to the following error:

```
error: --eval "CODE" and script file are mutually exclusive options

usage: octave [-HVWdfhiqvx] [--debug] [--doc-cache-file file] [--echo-commands]
       [--eval CODE] [--exec-path path] [--experimental-terminal-widget]
       [--gui] [--help] [--image-path path] [--info-file file]
       [--info-program prog] [--interactive] [--line-editing] [--no-gui]
       [--no-history] [--no-init-file] [--no-init-path] [--no-line-editing]
       [--no-site-file] [--no-window-system] [--norc] [-p path]
       [--path path] [--persist] [--server] [--silent] [--traditional]
       [--verbose] [--version] [file]
```

I believed that the problem could also have been having the functional nd the file with two different names. To solve this I have kept the same file name but changed the function to match it:

```
function _03_REPLACE_V04 (file_base)
```

Then in the batch:

```
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe" -q --eval "_03_REPLACE_V04('%a%')"
```

Leading to:

```
warning: function '_03_REPLACE_V04' defined within script file '\99_TOOLS\OCTAVE_FILES\_03_REPLACE_V04.m'
error: invalid call to script \99_TOOLS\OCTAVE_FILES\_03_REPLACE_V04.m
error: called from
    _03_REPLACE_V04
```

In other words still no way of making it work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Octave provides the `argv` function, which returns a cellstring array of all arguments passed to the octave executable at the time of launch, or in the case where it was used to launch a script, then this is the script's arguments.

So presumably all you have to do to get your directory from within octave is `argv(){1}`

If you would like to convert your filename to an absolute filename, you could also do this from within octave via the `make_absolute_filename` function.

---

Incidentally, a very useful command you should know of in octave is the `lookfor` command. Writing `lookfor arguments` in the terminal returns a list with all functions which have the word "arguments" in their description; `argv` is at the top of that list.

You can then do `help argv` to see more details on that command.